# Understanding Snippet of Javascript

Tags: javascript

My professor has given us the following snippet of Javascript which we are supposed to analyze:

```
function createMultiplyer(multiple) {
n = multiple;
return function(num) {
 return num * n;
 };
}

var fiveMultiplyer = createMultiplyer(15);
var x = fiveMultiplyer(10);
alert(x);
alert(fiveMultiplyer);
```

This piece of code outputs an alert containing the text "150" followed by another alert which reads `function(num) { return num * n; }`.  However, I cannot seem to understand why that is the case.

Can someone help me trace through the code and explain what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** Let's consider line

```
var fiveMultiplyer = createMultiplyer(15);
```

After it, `fiveMultiplyer` variable will have return value of `createMultiplyer` function (that's how functions work). And that return value is

```
function(num) {
  return num * n;
};
```

So, the code is similar to this (about `n` later)

```
var fiveMultiplyer = function(num) {
  return num * n;
};
```

**2** The next line is

```
var x = fiveMultiplyer(10);
```

Here we just invoke the function above. It also uses variable `n`: that variable is set in `createMultiplyer` function: `n = multiple;`. Thus, in our case `n` is `15` and `fiveMultiplyer(10)` is equivalent to `10 * 15`.

That's all. Hope it helps.

**edit**
I'll also note that `n` is a global variable the way it's declared. So, you can access it from anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fiveMultiplyer = createMultiplyer(15); // Create a function that multiplies with 15
```

This function is locally known as `fiveMultiplier`

```
var x = fiveMultiplyer(10); // Invoke the multiply-by-15 with argument 10
```

The result is locally known as `x`

```
alert(x); // 150
alert(fiveMultiplyer); // The definition of multiply-by-15 as 
                       // it is returned from createMultiplyer
```

---

```
function createMultiplyer(multiple) { // Returns a new function which 
                                      // multiplies with "multiple"
 [var] n = multiple; // Note: "var" should have been used to keep "n"
                     // in scope (within "createMultiplyer").
 return function(num) { // Return definition of multiplier function
  return num * n; // "num" = arg. when invoked, "n" = multiplier at 
                  // define time (when "createMultiplyer" was called)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can have a variable which acts as a function too.

```
var fiveMultiplyer = createMultiplyer(15); 
    You are calling a CreateMultiplyer(15) function. 
    This function returns you another function and that is associated 
    with the fiveMultiplyer var.
var x = fiveMultiplyer(10);
    You are actually invoking the function which was returned in previous step. 
    hence evaluating the value to 10 * 15 = 150
alert(x);
   As explained this returns 150
alert(fiveMultiplyer);
   As explained this returns the complete function 
   returned by createMultiplyer().
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think of it is as a class or object.  var fiveMultiplyer is creating an object that holds a value n = 15 and has a function that accepts a number and multiplies it by n.

In Java this would look something like this

```
public class Multiplyer {
  private int n;

  public Multiplyer(int n) {
    this->n = n;
  }

  public int multiple (int m) {
    return n*m;
  }
}

Multiplyer myMultiplyer = new Multiplyer(15);

System.out.println( myMultiplyer.multiple(10) );
```

In the JavaScript however the variable fiveMultiplye does not have to call its method, you simple pass it the required variables and it calls the method and returns for you.

Hope that helps.